# How do you dispose of old raisins?

Tags: food-safety

I worry cause I know they are harmful to dogs so what is the safest way to dispose of them. Thanks.

Comment: In the compost bin ? or the trash? Or Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: Put them in most any cookie recipe.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because while your intention is laudable, this is a cooking site, not our sister site Pets SE.

Answer (score 2):

Use any solid, sealable container (eg a screw-top jar) that you wanted to dispose of anyway, fill it with what you want to dispose of, seal it, and throw the whole in the garbage. If you think your dogs are really rummaging through the thrash and might manage to undo the lid: Some superglue in the threads should take care of that.

Alternative (if your plumbing can take it and we are not talking several kilograms): Down the toilet.

Answer (score 1):

You might try putting them with dried prunes, adding water to just short of covering them, and stewing gently.  The raisins soften, and the compote has just a bit of spicy taste from the raisins.  Good on oatmeal.

Answer (score 0):

As raisins keep almost indefinitely you shouldn't have to. But if for some reason you do need to, just put them out for the birds, in a feeder or on a bird table that the dog can't reach. For example I've got some that are very poor quality (hard and gritty) which I'll probably mix in with the bird seed.